# Comparing user input string git bash

Tags: git-bash

I'm trying to develop a basic CLI tool that asks the user for confirmation before executing a potentially irreversible action.
The following is the validation script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Resetting Database. This will delete all current data in the DB."
read -p "Are you sure you wish to proceed? (y/n): " confirm
if ["$confirm" = "y"]; then 
  echo "Awesome!"
fi
```

I ran the above script with the -x flag to see what's happening, and the following is the output:

```
+ echo 'Resetting Database. This will delete all current data in the DB.'
Resetting Database. This will delete all current data in the DB.
+ read -p 'Are you sure you wish to proceed? (y/n): ' confirm
Are you sure you wish to proceed? (y/n): y 
+ '[y' = 'y]'
./test-script.sh: line 4: [y: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would validate that script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ first.

You would see:

```
^-- SC1035 (error): You need a space after the [ and before the ].
```

That refers to [SC1035](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1035):

> Bourne shells are very whitespace sensitive.
> Adding or removing spaces can drastically alter the meaning of a script.
>
> In these cases, ShellCheck has noticed that you're missing a space at the position indicated.

For you:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Resetting Database. This will delete all current data in the DB."
read -rp "Are you sure you wish to proceed? (y/n): " confirm
if [ "$confirm" = "y" ]; then 
  echo "Awesome!"
fi
```

Comment: Note: if you can afford one more executable, [`gum`](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum) is awesome for that kind of bash script.

Comment: Thank you for the ShellCheck suggestion. I was not aware of this until now. I'll also check out gum!